# Unable to Access Spinnaker from my Machine's IP

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, spinnaker

Installation of Spinnaker is done on an AWS ec2-instance. I want to access the docker from my local windows machine.

I have tried all these so far

1) Edit /etc/apache/ports.conf and remove change Listen 127.0.0.1:9000 to Listen 9000
1a) Add a reverse proxy for ports you wish to open in Apache
2) You may edit service files in /opt/spinnaker/conf to disable the bind to local host. Change localhost to domain name or 0.0.0.0

but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure that you have setup spinnaker ssh tunnel as described here -http://www.spinnaker.io/v1.0/docs/installing-and-running-spinnaker#aws-setup ?

Comment: Yes. I believe I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck on this too after having done the same things you mention. I got it working by also changing 127.0.0.1:9000 to *:9000 in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/spinnaker.conf.